# How to let user sign up for an account and user id at same time with rails 4 and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms, multi-tenant

I am trying to build a multitenant app using rails 4 and devise. The design I am attempting is that an account has one owner(primary user) and has many users. I have an account being added along with the nested form adding the user. I'm not sure if I have issue with the schema I'm attempting to populate or if I am missing a step that would allow me to add an account and user at the same time, with the account record being populated with the owner_id (primary user) and the user being populated with the account_id.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current_id
  has_many :users
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'

  validates :owner, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :account
end

class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.build_owner
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Successfully Created Account!'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain, owner_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
    end
end
```

Views/Accounts/new.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">

    <h2>Create an Account</h2>

    <%= form_for @account do |f| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :owner do |o| %>
        <%= form_group_for o, :email do %>
          <%= o.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        <% end %>
        <%= form_group_for o, :password do %>
          <%= o.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
        <% end %>
        <%= form_group_for o, :password_confirmation do %>
          <%= o.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <%= form_group_for f, :name, opts= {:label => "Company Name"} do %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

App/Helper/Form_Helper (view call this)

```
module FormHelper
  def errors_for(form, field)
    content_tag(:p, form.object.errors[field].try(:first), class: 'help-block')
  end

  def form_group_for(form, field, opts={}, &block)

    if opts.has_key?(:label)
       label = opts.fetch(:label)
    else
     label = field.to_s
    end

    has_errors = form.object.errors[field].present?

    content_tag :div, class: "form-group #{'has-error' if has_errors}" do
      concat form.label(label, class: 'control-label')
      concat capture(&block)
      concat errors_for(form, field)
    end
  end
end
```

DB/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140629124546) do

  create_table "accounts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "clients", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.text     "address"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "clients", ["account_id"], name: "index_clients_on_account_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "account_id"
  end

  add_index "users", ["account_id"], name: "index_users_on_account_id"
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Currently the design creates both the account and user records. The user record is populated with the account_id, but the account_id isn't populated with the owner_id (user_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely in your associations, which are currently incomplete and a bit inaccurate.

If a model's attribute holds a foreign key, like the owner_id attribute on your Account model, then it *belongs_to* that model it is referencing. Think of it like a cattle brand. If you have the ids of other models on you, you belong to those models. You current have a has_one where you need a belongs_to.

You will also need to set up the inverse association, which is currently lacking in your user model.

Assuming you actually will only ever want a user to be associated with one account (as opposed to a user being on more than one account), you could rearrange your associations like this:

```
#models/account.rb

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end


#models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :account
  has_one :owned_account, class_name: 'Account', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
end
```

Proper association setup will hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: I made the changes, but the result seemed to be the same, the account record was populated with an owner_id, but the user record didn't get the account_id populated. It seems that the user record is saving before the account id is being generated thus the account_id is nil on the user record.

Comment: I see. Well, it's not an elegant solution, but now that your associations are well setup, in the Account#create action, after @account.save, you can put in a line like: @account.owner.update(account_id: @account.id)